# Construction of a linear system stratifying certain requirements

Tags: control-theory

> Construct a linear system  $$ \begin{cases} \dot x = Ax + Bu \\ y=Cx
>  \end{cases} $$ that satisfies all the following requirements:
>
> - 4th order
> - 1 input & 1 output
> - Unstable
> - Stabilizable & detectable
> - Rank of controlability matrix = Rank of obeservability matrix = 2
> - $C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ is first order, i.e., can be written as $\frac{\alpha}{s+\beta}$ for some scalar constants $\alpha$ and
>     $\beta$.

**Attempt**

*Requirement 1&2:* 
$$
A_{4 \times 4}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix},
\hspace{0.6cm}
B_{4 \times 1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
b_{3} \\
b_{4} 
\end{bmatrix},
\hspace{0.6cm}
C_{1 \times 4}=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix},
\hspace{0.6cm}
x_{4 \times 1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} 
\end{bmatrix},
\hspace{0.6cm}
u_{1 \times 1},
\hspace{0.6cm}
y_{1 \times 1},
$$

---

*Requirement 3:*

Real$\{ \lambda_i \}_{i=1,2,3,4}$ is zero or positive. Let $a$ be non-negative real number, and $b,c,d$ be any real numbers. 
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=(a-\lambda)(b-\lambda)(c-\lambda)(d-\lambda)=0
$$

---

*Requirement 4:*

Stabilizable if $$
Rank(
\begin{bmatrix}
sI-A & B \\
\end{bmatrix}
)=4
$$

Detectable if $$
Rank(
\begin{bmatrix}
sI-A \\
C \\
\end{bmatrix}
)=4
$$

---

*Requirement 5:*

The controllability matrix is given by
$$
\mathcal{C}=
\begin{bmatrix}
B & AB & A^2B & A^3B
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The obeservability matrix is given by
$$
\mathcal{O}=
\begin{bmatrix}
C \\
CA \\
CA^2 \\
CA^3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$Rank(\mathcal{C})=Rank(\mathcal{O})=2$

---

*Requirement 6:*

The transfer function is given by
$$
\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{\alpha}{s+\beta}
$$
for some scalar constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

---

**Question**

I understand all the requirements and implications but I am not sure how to starting actually constructing. Any help?

Comment: each of these requirement are describing conditions on your matrices, e.g. 4th order = start with A as a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: @EduardoElael Please refer to the updated post. I do get these requirement but I am still unable to _actually_ construct the linear system.

Comment: In Req 3. positiveness of "at least" one of the eigenvalues is enough, you don't need all eigenvalues being positive. In Req. 4 you only need to check the unstable eigenvalues. Req 6. means only one eigenvalue is "both" controllable and observable.

Comment: I don't get your comments about requirement 4 and 6. Can you explain it further?

Comment: $sI-A$ is always full rank if $s$ is different from the eigenvalues of $A$, by definition. So for the rank condition you only need to check for $s=\lambda_i(A)$, eigenvalues of $A$. But you don't need to check for the stable eigenvalues, because you are not interested in them being controllable or not, since they are  already stable. So, for stabilizability, you only need to check the unstable eigenvalues being controllable.

Comment: Only observable and controllable states are seen in the transfer function. So the eigenvalue $\lambda=-\beta$ must be both controllable and observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Hints:

Start attempting with a 4x4 diagonal matrix for $A$ for simplicity(**Requirement 1&2**). You know that you need a positive eigen value for instability (**Requirement 3**), I would start with $A = \text{Diag}(1,-1, -1, -1)$ beacause it is the simplest. As $A² = I$ and $A³ = A$, you get your *"Rank of controlability matrix = Rank of obeservability matrix = 2*" for free (**Requirement 5**).

Now you can go to the apparent paradox of having a 1st degree TF with a 4th order system. That means some part of your state is not controllable/observable, e.g. with $C = B^t = [1~0~0~0]$ (**Requirement 6**). Because I have choose the $C$ and $B$ so that I can control and observe the unstable part of the state, it will be Stabilizable/Detectable (**Requirement 4**).

Ps: Not sure you are aware, but on your Stabilizable/Detectable definition, that must be true for those values of $s$ equal the unstable eigenvalues (greater or equal than zero).

Comment: I understood requirements 1,2,3,5, but i'm confused about 6 and 4. With your choice of $A$, which states are not controllable/observable? $x_1$ because of the positive eigenvalue?  I also do not understand the last comment on Stabilizable/Detectable definitions. Can you please clarify that too?

Comment: With my choice of A, $x_2,x_3,x_4$ are "steered together". And the last comment was just because in your definition of Stabilizable you said "Stabilizable if Rank ... =4".. But it *only* needs to be 4 for $s=1$ which is the unstable eigenvalue.

Comment: So how to know which states are the unobservable/uncontrollable states? I thought since you chose $C$ to be $[1~ 0 ~0 ~0]$ then you are only observing $x_1$ since it is the unobservable state. No?

Comment: You are correct, by my choice of C I'm only observing $x_1$. As, in some sense, $x_2, x_3, x_4$ would be multiples of each other, I could not observe all of them (distinguish), but I could still observe at least one of them, if I have chosen $C=[1~1~0~0]$ for example.